# Could not import package. Warning SQL72012: The object exists in the target

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I exported my Azure database using Tasks > Export Data-tier Application in to a .bacpac file. Recently when I tried to import it into my local database server (Tasks > Import Data-tier Application), I encountered this error:

```
Could not import package.
Warning SQL72012: The object [MyDatabase_Data] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Warning SQL72012: The object [MyDatabase_Log] exists in the target, but it will not be dropped even though you selected the 'Generate drop statements for objects that are in the target database but that are not in the source' check box.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 12824, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 The sp_configure value 'contained database authentication' must be set to 1 in order to alter a contained database.  You may need to use RECONFIGURE to set the value_in_use.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET CONTAINMENT = PARTIAL 
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END


Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 5 ALTER DATABASE statement failed.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
           FROM   [master].[dbo].[sysdatabases]
           WHERE  [name] = N'$(DatabaseName)')
    BEGIN
        ALTER DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)]
            SET CONTAINMENT = PARTIAL 
            WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    END

 (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
```

I followed the advice on other posts and tried to run this on SQL Azure database:

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

However, it says

```
Could not find stored procedure 'sp_configure'.
```

I understand the equivalent statement in Azure is: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-scoped-configuration-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

What is the equivalent statement to "sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;"?

Comment: You need to enable `contained database authentication` on your on-premises SQL Server.  It's always enabled in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Please run that sp_configure on your on-premise SQL Server instance, do not run that statement on Azure SQL Database.

Comment: This works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 77):

The solution is to execute this against the `master` database of your local/on-premise SQL Server:

```
sp_configure 'contained database authentication', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Thank you to [David Browne - Microsoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft) and [Alberto Morillo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8184139/alberto-morillo) for the quick solution.

Comment: What does this query actually do?

Comment: This answer should be selected as the solution to the problem.

Comment: Yep, this is it - worked perfectly for me after running these commands to my local master db.

Comment: Yes, how do you use this.  So I ran it.  What now?  Re-try the installation?  Or is it "fixed" now as if the installation succeeded the first time?

Comment: The question is about SQL Azure, not a local DB. This doesn't work

Comment: This is just one of many causes. Your SQL Server version can be the cause.

Comment: This worked for me!  Restoring bacpac to local SQL 2019 Dev installation.

Comment: Run the script against the master. Restore once more. Voila, no error on import.

Comment: SQL Server 2019 tells me the error, "The configuration option 'contained database authentication' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option," when I try to run this.  I don't see the option in the advanced options on the database.  Any idea what else I am missing?

Comment: 'sp_configure' won't work on Azure SQL database. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and it got fixed by importing the bacpac via command prompt. In link [Import Bacpac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-import?tabs=azure-powershell) go to SQLPackage section and run the command provided there.

```
sqlpackage.exe /a:import /tcs:"Data Source=<serverName>.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=<migratedDatabase>;User Id=<userId>;Password=<password>" /sf:AdventureWorks2008R2.bacpac /p:DatabaseEdition=Premium /p:DatabaseServiceObjective=P6
```

Comment: This led me to discover I had a view that was based on a table that had changed and now had conflicting column names - if the error message wasn't truncated in Azure then I could have saved a lot of time!

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was to directly copy DB from azure to my localhost.

1. Create a new database in your local DB server.
2. Right-click on a new database, Tasks -> Import data.
3. Provide data for Azure db:
   [image]
4. Provide data for your localhost:
   [image]
5. Click Next. Check the first checkbox to select all.
6. On the next form choose -> Run immediately
7. Wait until the process is completed.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

**Using the Azure portal to Import a bacpac:**

The Collation chosen in the first step of the Azure SQL Import wizard, is important!

It needs to match the Collation in the source DB that was used to create the bacpac.

The sqlpackage and SSMS methods do NOT need this step.